# Plot multiple sets of points in R

Tags: r, statistics, plot

I have multiple sets of xy pairs that I want to plot.  I want each set of xy pairs to be connected by a line.  In other words the goal is to have multiple experimental instances each approximated by a line plotted on one plot.  Also how would I colour the lines differently?

The plot function does what I want, but takes on one set of xy pairs:
`plot(x, y, ...)`

Can this function be made to take multiple sets or is there another function for that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To do this with the normal plot command, I would usually create one plot and then add more lines using the `lines()` function.

Otherwise you can use lattice or ggplot2.  Here's some data:

```
df <- data.frame(a = runif(10), b = runif(10), c = runif(10), x = 1:10)
```

You can use `xyplot()` from lattice:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(a + b + c ~ x, data = df, type = "l", auto.key=TRUE)
```

Or `geom_line()` in ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(melt(df, id.vars="x"), aes(x, value, colour = variable,
        group = variable)) + geom_line() + theme_bw()
```

Here's another example including points at each pair (from [this post on the learnr blog](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/ggplot2-version-of-figures-in-lattice-multivariate-data-visualization-with-r-part-4/)):

```
library(lattice)
dotplot(VADeaths, type = "o", auto.key = list(lines = TRUE,
     space = "right"), main = "Death Rates in Virginia - 1940",
     xlab = "Rate (per 1000)")
```

And the same plot using ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(melt(VADeaths), aes(value, X1, colour = X2,
             group = X2))
p + geom_point() + geom_line() + xlab("Rate (per 1000)") +
         ylab("") + opts(title = "Death Rates in Virginia - 1940")
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: Error: could not find function "dotplot"  Do I need something from CRAN to use this?

Comment: Okay I see the library calls now.  Thanks for your answer!